# DIVs dynamic position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I'm working on a project to create a website in which I need 3 divs to appear/disapear when ticking some checkboxes (one per div). I made an exemple here : http://jsbin.com/okevuy/1/edit
My problem (quite complicated to explain) is that I want the first ticked DIV appears at the top (no matter which one is triggered first) and the next ticked DIV below the first. If the first is hidden by unticking the checkbox, the second one moves to the top, and the next ticked appears below, etc...
Can some one help in doing that and show me how to ? 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: If they second is checked before  the first do you want the second to remain on top or should the first checkbox take the first place and the second move down?

Comment: Preferably, I want it to go below the other if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

markup: Add a wrapper around the boxes

```
<div id="mianwrapper" >
   <div id='red_div' class='divs'></div>
   <div id='blue_div' class='divs'></div>
   <div id='green_div' class='divs'></div>
</div>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#checkbox_red_div').click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')){ checkPosition("red_div"); $('#red_div').show(10); $('#red_div').animate({
        'opacity': '1',
            'margin-left': '0px'

    }, 300)}
    else $('#red_div').animate({
        'opacity': '0',
            'margin-left': '-80px',
            "display":"none"


    }, 300 , function(){$('#red_div').fadeOut(100)});
});
$('#checkbox_blue_div').click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { checkPosition("blue_div"); $('#blue_div').show(10); $('#blue_div').animate({
        'opacity': '1',
            'margin-left': '0px'
    }, 300 )}
    else $('#blue_div').animate({
        'opacity': '0',
            'margin-left': '-80px',

    }, 300 ,  function(){$('#blue_div').fadeOut(100)} );
});
$('#checkbox_green_div').click(function () {
    checkPosition("green_div");
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){ $('#green_div').show(10); $('#green_div').animate({
        'opacity': '1',
            'margin-left': '0px'
    }, 300)}
    else $('#green_div').animate({
        'opacity': '0',
            'margin-left': '-80px',

    }, 300 ,  function(){$('#green_div').fadeOut(100)});
});

function checkPosition(getBox)
{
  $("#"+getBox).appendTo("#mianwrapper");
}

});
```

Css: 
Small change in css

```
#red_div{
   border:solid 1px red;
   width:100px;
   height:50px;
   opacity:1;
   float:left;
   clear:left;
}

#blue_div{
   border:solid 1px blue;
   width:100px;
   height:50px;
   opacity:1;
   float:left;
   clear:left;
}

#green_div{
   border:solid 1px green;
   width:100px;
   height:50px;
   opacity:1;
   float:left;
   clear:left;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm ! Thanks everyone else for your answers too !

Answer (score 3):

How this http://jsbin.com/okevuy/5/

example code

```
$('#red_div').animate({
                'height': '50',
                 'opacity': '1',
                'margin-left': '0px'
        }, 300);
        else $('#red_div').animate({
              'height': '0',
                'opacity': '0',
                'margin-left': '-80px'
        }, 300);
    });
```

Comment: This helps me yes, thanks, but would it be possible to position the last checked below the others already shown ?

Comment: never mind, answer of Shinov T made it, thanks for your time dude !

Answer (score 0):

I've edit your example: http://jsbin.com/okevuy/7/edit. Check it. What have been changed: "height: 50px" if div visible, height:0px otherwise.
Hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is still taking spaces since you are just moving them instead of hiding them. You can try hide/show the div when animate is complete:

```
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('#red_div').show().animate({
        'opacity': '1',
            'margin-left': '0px'
    }, 300);
    else $('#red_div').animate({
        'opacity': '0',
            'margin-left': '-80px'
    }, 300, function(){ $(this).hide();});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WqbH4/